# How to parse single-quoted string with nested quote-operator in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, split

I have following string:

```
my $str = 'ab cd q{ef gh '\"} ij';
```

I would like to split the string as:

```
$VAR1 = ['ab', 'cd', 'q{ef gh '\"}', 'ij'];
```

I have used parse_line() to parse it:

```
my @arr = parse_line('\s+', 1, $str);
```

However, since the single-quote within the input string is not escaped and parse_line() cannot interpret q() operator, I'm getting empty array as output.

**To be precise, I want to treat the quoted-string as a single word, irrespective of its content.** The only solution I can think of is to write a custom function which can interpret the quote-operator. Is there any simple way to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you've misplaced backslash `ab cd q{ef gh \'"} ij'`

Answer (score 2):

```
\s+(?![^{]*})
```

You can split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/33

If you have nested `{}` you can use this.

```
{(?:[^{}]*|(?R))*}\K|\s
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/34

Comment: That's brilliant, sir. I was trying to sort this out myself. Good answer!

Comment: Note that the `q` operator 1) allows the delimiters and `\ ` to be escaped, 2) allows a variety of delimiters, and 3) allows whitespace between the `q` and the delimiter. But it's not clear whether these should be supported or not.

Comment: I mean that `q {foo}` and `q{foo}` are equivalent. And so is `q!foo!`. At least in Perl. It's not clear whether the OP wants to support this or not.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I want to support all such combinations. In a nutshell, I want to treat the quoted-string as a single word, irrespective of its content.

Comment: @ikegami can you link a doc for perl where it's explained what delimiters are allowed?